# YouTube v3 API upload to channel

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I have to migrate my PHP scripts using YouTube's v2 API to v3.

I'm trying this example to upload a video:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#resumable_uploads

I can authenticate my Google account for my app, the only problem is that the video is being uploaded to my Google+ YouTube channel and not to my original channel. (They both belong to the same Google account).

I was not able to solve this problem with the v2 API but selecting the "default" channel in "Channel switcher" (https://www.youtube.com/channel_switcher) did help.

How can I tell the v3 API which channel to upload to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of writing, the ability to choose which channel to upload a video to is only available to [YouTube content partners](https://www.youtube.com/yt/partners/).

The `videos.insert` method supports an optional parameter `onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel`, which takes in a a YouTube channel ID value as a string.  You must also provide your YouTube CMS auth credentials for the `onBehalfOfContentOwner` parameter as well.

YouTube provides some explanation:

> This [onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel] parameter is intended for YouTube content partners that own and
>   manage many different YouTube channels. It allows content owners to
>   authenticate once and perform actions on behalf of the channel
>   specified in the parameter value, without having to provide
>   authentication credentials for each separate channel.

Relevant API documentation for `videos.insert` [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert).