# Choose channel to upload Youtube API Video

Tags: python, oauth, youtube-api

I am trying to find how to upload a video to a specific channel that my account has (now it has about 8 channels) but the docs aren't specific about that.

My code is exactly the same the upload example shows:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#upload_a_video

but as I said, there isn't anywhere how to choose a channel... So the videos are being uploaded to my main channel.

Comment: If you have a YouTube content partner account you can use `onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel` parameter I believe. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#parameters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758800/youtube-v3-api-upload-to-channel