# What are the requirements for using the YouTube api to post to a specific channel?

Tags: youtube-api

I need to post videos to specific YouTube channels via the V3 api managed by a single account.

I am trying to use the onBehalfOfContentOwner & onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel fields to upload the video but I'm somewhat confused about the account requirements in order to enable this.

My understanding is that it is only possible to do this with channels that are managed by a Partner Account. I have set up my account as a partner account and the next thing the documentation talks about is using a CMS account. To give permissions to manage channels. The documentation seems to suggest that a CMS account is generated automatically once you become a partner account, but I can see no sign of this.

The documentation then goes on to talk about having to have a Partner Content ID in order to get a **Full** CMS account. This appears to be something that you have to apply for.

Is it really necessary that the account and channels have to be set up in this way or is there an easier way to manage this?

Comment: You should be able to post on channels if the requests are correctly oauth2 authenticated with the  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload` scope. `onBehalfOfContentOwner` should not be needed.

Comment: I think this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758800/youtube-v3-api-upload-to-channel) can help provide an answer.